# javascript date format "y-m-d h:m:s" to "d/m/Y"

Tags: javascript

I want to change my date format (2017-12-13 00:00:00) to 13/12/2017.

```
var venuDate = response[index]['event_date']; // 2017-12-13 00:00:00
```

How can i do this.!

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: Actually i tried some format but didnot work.!! Exact format ?

Comment: @A.J.Uppal am getting venuDate  = 2017-12-13 00:00:00

Comment: Can you add in what you have tried to achieve the desired format? Maybe that way someone could help point out where you are going wrong

Comment: am getting this in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Date` constructor:

```
var venuDate = response[index]['event_date'];
var curDate = new Date(venuDate);
var date = curDate.getDate();
var month = curDate.getMonth()+1;
var year = curDate.getFullYear();
console.log(date+"/"+month+"/"+year)
```

Comment: why i am getting 13/11/2017 instaed of 13/12/2017

Comment: because the month is 0 indexed, see the edit